# android - connect to API without pressing button

Tags: android, xml, api, request

I'm making an app that connects to an API via some middleware. 
What my app currently does is when you press a button, it invokes a GET request to get selected data from the database in an XML format. 
How do I get certain data from the database without having to press a button, so I can turn the elements into different buttons, which link off to other pages (which are sports teams)

Here is the code I've got:

```
    package cnet343.sportsapp;

    import java.io.IOException;..

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    findViewById(R.id.my_button).setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_button);
    b.setClickable(false);
    new LongRunningGetIO().execute();
}

private class LongRunningGetIO extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, String> {

    protected String getASCIIContentFromEntity(HttpEntity entity) throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
       InputStream in = entity.getContent();
         StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
         int n = 1;
         while (n>0) {
             byte[] b = new byte[4096];
             n =  in.read(b);
             if (n>0) out.append(new String(b, 0, n));
         }
         return out.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
         HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
         HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
         HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("apiaddressgoeshere");
         String text = null;
         try {
               HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
               HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
               text = getASCIIContentFromEntity(entity);
         } catch (Exception e) {
             return e.getLocalizedMessage();
         }
         return text;
    }   

    protected void onPostExecute(String results) {
        if (results!=null) {
            EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.my_edit);
            et.setText(results);
        }
        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_button);
        b.setClickable(true);
        }
    }
}
```

**note:** `apiaddressgoeshere` is private and confidential so don't want to share that on here

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling your async operation in button click you can simply call this in Activity **onCreate()**

```
package cnet343.sportsapp;

import java.io.IOException;..

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
findViewById(R.id.my_button).setOnClickListener(this);

//call here in Activity onCreate()
new LongRunningGetIO().execute();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_button);
b.setClickable(false);
//new LongRunningGetIO().execute();
}
```